# Query with multiple tables (get details of a registration)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to have a query using laravel that allows to get the details about a registration.  I have this route:

```
Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/registration/{regID}/info', [
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@getRegistrationInfo',
    'as'   =>'conferences.registrationInfo'
]);
```

When the user accesses this route I want to show the details of that specific registration of the user.

For example if the user John W. did a registration in a conference in which:

- selected 1 ticket/registration of the type "general" for him (John W.) and 1 ticket/registration of the type "plus" (for Jake W.)
- and the registration type "general" has a price of "0"
- and the registration type "plus" has a price of "1"
- and all_participants is "1" in the conferences table which means that is necessary to collect the name and surname of each participant, "0" means that is necessary to collect the name and surname only of the user that is doing the registration (the auth user)

In the registration table will be inserted:

```
id       status        conference_id         main_participant_id
1          I                 1                          1
```

In the participants table:

```
id    registration_id    registration_type_id       name        surname
1           1                   1                     John           W
2           1                   2                    Jake            W
```

The Registration types table is like:

```
id        name       price     ...
1         general       0
2          plus        1
```

The Conference table is like:

```
id       name                            date
1         conference name        2018-06-13
```

I want to have a query that allows to  show for a specific registration, when the user clicks in the link associated with the above route "Route::get('/conference/{id}/{slug?}/registration/{regID}/info", show for each ticket/registration type associated with that registration id, in this case, were 2 registration types (2 participants), so a query that allows to show a list with two list items showing the registration info like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>show the registration ID here</span>
        <span>Conference name: conference name</span>
        <span>Conference date: 2018-06-13</span>
        <span>Registration type: general</span>
        <span> Participant: John W</span>
        <span>Price: 0<span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>show the registration ID here</span>
        <span>Conference name: conference name</span>
        <span>Conference date: 2018-06-13</span>
        <span>Registration type: plus</span>
        <span> Participant: Jake W</span>
        <span>Price: 1<span>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Do you know how this can be achieved? Im not understanding how to do this properly, if it should be only one query or multiple queries. Do you know how to properly achieve a query this context?

---

Relevant models for the question:

Conference model:

```
class Conference extends Model
{
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }
}
```

Registration Type model:

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Registration', 'registration_registration_types');
    }
}
```

Registration model:

```
class Registration extends Model
{

    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'main_participant_id', 'id');
    }

    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function registration_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_registration_types');
    }

    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

    public function payment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Payment');
    }
}
```

Participant model:

```
class Participant extends Model
{
    public function registration(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }
    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
    }

}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','main_participant_id');
    }
}
```

Like:

```
public function getRegistrationInfo($regID){


        $q = Registration::
         with('conference', 'registration_types.participants')
         ->find($regID);

    }
```

it shows:

```
Table 'project.registration_registration_types'
doesn't exist (SQL: select `registration_types`.*, 
`registration_registration_types`.`registration_id` as 
`pivot_registration_id`, 
`registration_registration_types`.`registration_type_id` as 
`pivot_registration_type_id` from `registration_types` inner join 
`registration_registration_types` on `registration_types`.`id` = 
`registration_registration_types`.`registration_type_id` where 
 `registration_registration_types`.`registration_id` in (1))
```

Comment: A question with good details and no attempts. Have you tried anything to show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand exactly what you mean

`controller` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Registration;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function getRegistrationInfo($id ,$slug, $regID)
    {

        $registration = Registration::with('conference','Conference.registrationTypes','Conference.registrationTypes.participants')
        ->where('id',$regID)->first();
    return view('your_view_name',compact('registration'));

}
```

}

your `view` :

```
<ul>
@foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $key=>$registrationType)

     <li>
             <span>show the registration ID here : {{$registration->id}}</span> <br>
             <span>Conference name: conference name : {{$registration->conference->name}}</span><br>
             <span>Conference date: {{$registration->conference->date}}</span><br>
             <span>Registration type: {{$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name']}}</span><br>
             <span> Participant: {{$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]->participants[0]->name .' '.$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]->participants[0]->surname}}</span><br>
             <span>Price: {{$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['price']}}</span><br>
    </li>

@endforeach
</ul>
```

output :

```html
<ul>

         <li>
                 <span>show the registration ID here : 1</span> <br>
                 <span>Conference name: conference name : conferanse shomare 1</span><br>
                 <span>Conference date: 2018-06-06 00:00:00</span><br>
                 <span>Registration type: general</span><br>
                 <span> Participant: John w</span><br>
                 <span>Price: 0</span><br>
        </li>


         <li>
                 <span>show the registration ID here : 1</span> <br>
                 <span>Conference name: conference name : conferanse shomare 1</span><br>
                 <span>Conference date: 2018-06-06 00:00:00</span><br>
                 <span>Registration type: plus</span><br>
                 <span> Participant: Jake w</span><br>
                 <span>Price: 1</span><br>
        </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ops.. I see in `Registration` model and function `registration_types` you call `BelongsToMany` but parameters of that function like:

```
belongsToMany($related, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $relation)
```

may be you wrong table `registration_registration_types`

Comment: Thanks, like "        $q = Registration::with('conference', 'registration_registration_types.participants')->find($regID);
" appears "Call to undefined relationship [registration] on model [App\Registration].
".